# Управление консолью в python

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, библиотеку, позволяющую работать с консолью. Т.е. если туда уже выведена 2, то её можно заменить на 3 к примеру. Или это можно сделать поколдовав над sys.stdout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам стоит обратить внимание на библиотеку [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/curses.html).

Из интересного есть следующий вариант: можно вывести символ с кодом 8 (он сдвинет положение каретки вывода влево на одну позицию), после чего вывести нужный символ.

```
print('12', end='')
print('\x08', end='')
print('3')
```

Или просто

```
print('12\x083')
```